# I keep getting the error "Index 5 out of bounds for length 5" but don't know what to change

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm pretty new to coding so please bear with me, I am just experimenting with ways to shuffle an array for eventual use in shuffling a deck of cards in a card game I am creating in Java. I know that index 5 is out of bounds for length 5 but what is puzzling to me is that the error doesn't ALWAYS pop up. Sometimes I try to run my code and it works just fine, other times I get the error even if I haven't changed anything between times that I run it.

```
public class Card{

    public static void shuffle(Object[] array) {

        int noOfCards = array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {

            int s = i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));

            Object temp = array[s]; //this is the first line it says has a problem
            array[s] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strOfCards = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

        Card.shuffle(strOfCards); //this is the second line that has a problem
        for(int i = 0; i < strOfCards.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(strOfCards[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to change the flawed lines, any suggestions are welcome!
*** i have tried changing the number of letters in the string but then the error changes with it i.e. "Index 6 out of bounds for length 6"

Comment: int s = i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));
This is where you are going wrong. when i is the last index of the array adding something to it would just make you break out of the array. If you want it to wrap around how about taking mod nr of cards? So do something like this:
int s = (i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1))) %nrOfCards;
But rather than this I think it would help a lot more to search stack overflow for how to use Math.random to get an int in a range.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {
    int s = i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));
    Object temp = array[s]; //this is the first line it says has a problem
```

i varies from 0 to noOfCards - 1
Your random number expression varies from 0 to noOfCards - 2
So s varies from 0 to (2 * noOfCards) - 3

Then `array[s]` will throw an exception whenever s >= noOfCards

It doesn't happen every time you run it because sometimes the random numbers all happen to be under noOfCards

If you want to swap with a random other card then you could try:

```
Random random = new Random();
int s = (i + random.nextInt(noOfCards - 1)) % noOfCards;
```

I realise you're using this as a learning opportunity, but in case you weren't aware, there is a `Collections.shuffle` method that can be used to shuffle collections such as `ArrayList` in one command.

Answer (score 1):

Max index of array with length N is (N-1). Code should be like this:

```
public static void shuffle(Object[] array) {
    int noOfCards = array.length;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {
        int s = random.nextInt(noOfCards);

        Object temp = array[s];
        array[s] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line that causes the trouble:

```
int s = i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));
```

Whenever the value s is >= 5, the array[s] will point to something out of bound.

For example i can be 3, if Math.random() returns something like 0.5, then **3 + (int)(0.5 * 4)** is equal to **5**, which is out of bound (0..4)

It doesn't happen all the times, because some times the Math.random() generates small enough number, so the evaluation of s is smaller than 5.

To ensure that the value of s always in the range (0..4), you should modulo the result to 5.

Here is how the line should be:

```
int s = (i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1))) % 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
int s = i + (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));
```

to this

```
int s =  (int)(Math.random() * (noOfCards - 1));
```

just remove i variable from the above code

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that indices are zero-based in Java.

Note a couple of things:
- make things final if they're final
- use `SecureRandom`: it is more random than `Random`
- use the `nextInt(n)` method of SecureRandom to get an int in your range
- note the use of Streams to print out the result

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Card {

    public static void shuffle(final Object[] array) {

        final SecureRandom random    = new SecureRandom();

        final int          noOfCards = array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfCards; i++) {

            final int    s    = random.nextInt(noOfCards);

            final Object temp = array[s];

            array[s] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String[] strOfCards = {"A","B","C","D","E"};

        Card.shuffle(strOfCards);

        Stream.of(strOfCards).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you fancy using a `List` it's a bit more compact:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Card {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        final List<String> cards  = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

        IntStream.range(0, cards.size()).forEach(i ->
            Collections.swap(cards, i, random.nextInt(cards.size()))
        );
        cards.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

M getting the same issue with this code and still no idea how to solve it

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter \n"
            + "1 for 'Add new Employee'"
            + "\n 2 for 'Search in employee'"
            + "\n 3 for 'Exit'");
            
            int convertnumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
            
            if (convertnumber == 1)
            {
                addEmployee();
            }
            else if (convertnumber == 2)
            {
                String eId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID to search");
                searchEmplye(eId);
            }
            else if (convertnumber == 3)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Developed By: BC180401942 SHEHZAD ADEEL");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void searchEmplye(String eId)
    {
        try
        {
            String tokens[] = null;
            String id, name, dob, qual, expe, pays;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("empData.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            
            String line = br.readLine();
            
            if (line == null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Not found");
            }
            
            while (line != null)
            {
                tokens = line.split (",");
                id = tokens[0];
                name = tokens[1];
                dob = tokens[2];
                qual = tokens[3];
                expe = tokens[4];
                pays = tokens[5];
                
                Employee emp = new Employee (id, name, dob, qual, expe, pays);
                
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                list.add(emp);
                line = br.readLine();
                
                /*
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {
                    Employee p = (Employee) list.get(i);
                    if (eId.equals(p.getEmpId()))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee: \n"
                        + "Employee ID: " + p.getEmpId()
                        + " \n Employee Name: "  +p.getEmpName()
                        + " \n Employee DOB: " + p.getEmpDoB()
                        + " \n Qualification: " + p.getEmpQualf()
                        + " \n Experience: " + p.getEmpExp()
                        + " \n Pay Scal: " + p.getEmpPSacle()
                        );
                    }
                    */
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {
                    Employee p = (Employee) list.get(i);
                    if (eId.equals(p.getEmpId()))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Employee: \n" +
                        "EmpId: " + p.getEmpId() + "\n" +
                        "Name: " + p.getEmpName() + "\n" +
                        "DoB: " + p.getEmpDoB() + "\n" +
                        "Qualification: " + p.getEmpQualf() + "\n" +
                        "Experience: " + p.getEmpExp() + "\n" +
                        "PayScale: " + p.getEmpPScale() );
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Not found");
                    }
                }
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void addEmployee()
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee ID: ");
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: ");
            String dob = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter DoB (year): ");
            String qual = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Qualification: ");
            String exp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee experience (in months): ");
            String pays = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee Pay Scale (in number): ");
            
            Employee emp = new Employee (id, name, dob, qual, exp, pays);
            list.add(emp);
            /*
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID ");
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name ");
            String dob = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter DOB ");
            String qualification = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter qualification ");
            String experience = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee Experience");
            String paScale = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee pay scale ");
            
            Employee emp = new Employee(id, name, qualification, experience, paScale);
            list.add(emp);
            */
            
            String line;
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("empData.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                emp = (Employee) list.get(i);
                //line = emp.getEmpId() + "," + emp.getEmpName() + "," + emp.getEmpDoB() + "," + emp.getEmpQualf() + "," + emp.getEmpExp() + "," + emp.getEmpPSacle();
                
                line = emp.getEmpId() + "," +
                emp.getEmpName() + "," +
                emp.getEmpDoB() + "," +
                emp.getEmpQualf() + "," +
                emp.getEmpPScale();
                
                pw.println(line);
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println(ioEx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kevin-le need your expertise with this

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30529182)